# jquery ajax post,data is not sending to server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX call to a Struts2 Action class via jQuery ajax.

I am sending the json data to the server from my client. If I use "GET" in `$.ajax()`, the data is transferred to server. If I replace GET with "POST" in `$.ajax()`,the data is not transferred to server.

My code,

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'login.action',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  data:
  {
    jsonData: JSON.stringify(
    {
      number:"10",
      name:"ramesh"          
    })

  },
  success: function (data)
  {
     printStudentDetails(data);
  }
});
```

In firebug, while using GET,the json data is visible as

```
jsonData    {"number":"10","name":"ramesh"}
```

While using POST,the json data is visible as like this,

```
jsonData=%7B%22number%22%3A34%2C%22name%22%3A34%2C%22
```

What is the solution to send the data to the server using POST.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544324/differences-between-post-and-get-in-jquery-ajax

Comment: You have an extra comma in the object your passing to `JSON.stringify`. Firefox won't choke on it, but IE will.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working exactly as I would expect it to. It is stringifying your JSON data, and what you're seeing in the POST is HTML encoded. If you want to send your JSON data directly, get rid of the `JSON.stringify`.

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'login.action',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  data:
  {
      number:"10",
      name:"ramesh"
  },
  success: function (data)
  {
     printStudentDetails(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending JSON to the server, you're sending form params. remove the contentType.

```
url: 'login.action',
//contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: 'json',
```

Comment: And you're sure this has nothing to do with how you are retrieving the data on the server? i guarantee it is sending the data to the server in one way or another.

Comment: in server,iam using java struts2 action class,

Comment: and i'm not familiar with that language

Comment: i am sure it is not sending to the server bcoz at server side i tested it

Comment: you proved that it is sending the data in your question. You can see the data in firebug.